# How can I make bandit skip B101 within tests?

Tags: python, bandit-python

I'm using bandit to check my code for potential security issues:

```
bandit -r git-repository/
```

However, the most common item found by bandit is [B101](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b101_assert_used.html). It is triggered by assert statements within tests. I use pytest, so this is not a concern, but a good practice. I've now created a `.bandit` file with

```
[bandit]
skips: B101
```

But that also skips a lot of other code. Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A possible solution is to tell `bandit` to skip tests altogether. Assuming your code lives in a `src` subfolder, run

```sh
bandit --configfile bandit.yaml --recursive src
```

with the following `bandit.yaml` in the project's root directory

```yaml
# Do not check paths including `/tests/`:
# they use `assert`, leading to B101 false positives.
exclude_dirs:
    - '/tests/'
```

There is a [bunch](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/issues/346) of [related](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/issues/488) [issues](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/issues/345) and [pull requests](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/pull/450).

**Update:** I like [Diego's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69995301) better.

Answer (score 18):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit/pull/450#issuecomment-724777229),

> when using `--recursive` the whole path is `fnmatch`ed against the
> `glob_list`, therefore an `--exclude_dir` expression `test_*.py` doesn't
> matches and excludes (py)test files in subdirectories, for that
> `*/test_*.py` is needed.

The following configuration should solve your problem:

```
assert_used:
  skips: ["*/test_*.py", "*/test_*.py"]
```

Comment: FWIW I had to update an old codebase from 1.5.1 to 1.74 to get this to work

Comment: `**/test_*.py` glob can be used for deeper nested test modules.

Answer (score 17):

Just wanted to add to the answers above and mention the toml equivalent of skipping `assert_used` for specific files:

```ini
[tool.bandit.assert_used]
skips = ['*_test.py', '*/test_*.py']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can configure files that skip this check. This is often useful when you use assert statements in test cases.

```
bandit --configfile bandit.yaml
```

with the following bandit.yaml in the project's root directory

```
assert_used:
  skips: ['*_test.py', 'test_*.py']
```

[Link](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b101_assert_used.html) to the original doc

Answer (score 2):

Based on [documentation](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html), your config should look like
`skips: ['B101']`, not `skips: B101` (which you have).

EDIT:
Ok, so if I understand correctly, you want to skip `B101` on your `tests` folder.
I am not aware of any way to specify this, but I can think of hack of a sort - just run bandit two times - once ignoring `tests`, and once only on tests skipping `B101`. I know, it's not most elegant way, but it should solve your problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I have in my question where I wrote it's not what I want

Comment: `skips: ['B101']` and `skips: B101` are not the same thing. Are you sure you have the right thing in your config?

Comment: @ThrowAwayAccount Yes, I am. As stated in the question, I'm not asking for a solution to skip all B101 checks. I'm asking to skip B101 only for code in a given directory.

Comment: @MartinThoma that wasn't clear from your question, so I was answering something else.
So, you want to skip B101 only in /test directory?

Comment: Yes, I only want to skip B101 within the tests directory. In other directories, I want to still have this.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Edited my answer with possible solution.

Comment: For the hack: Can I have two different configurations for bandit? Is there something like "inheritence" for bandit configuration?

Comment: No idea about "inheritance", but you can specify your used config in your CLI `bandit` command.
Now the rest depends on your specific usecase - I use precommit, where I can run bandit two times and specify config there each time (as file or just args). Same can be done in GitHub Actions. You can also create simple shell script with these defined bandit checks and run it instead of directly using CLI.

Answer (score 1):

How I achieved `bandit` skip `B101` within tests in Visual Studio Code:

1. in the project's root I have `bandit.yaml` file with the following content:

> ```
> assert_used:
>     skips: ["*/test_*.py"]
> ```

2. In the `settings.json` file I have:

> ```
> "python.linting.banditArgs": [
>     "-r",
>     "--configfile",
>     "${workspaceFolder}/bandit.yaml"
> ],
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.bandit]
exclude_dirs = [".venv", "tests"]
skips = ["B307"]
```

From the command line I just add `-c pyproject.toml` and `bandit` reads the configuration from there.

In VSCode:

```
"python.linting.banditArgs": [
    "--configfile",
    "pyproject.toml"
]
```